# Github Actions: set-output does not seem to work

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a [workflow](https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/actions/runs/526544621/workflow) that executes a bunch of fuzz tests and, at the end, calculates the total number of files in all `crashers` sub-directories. Later, in another job, I use that number to send a notification to Slack. But, for some reason, `::set-output` produces no output and, most importantly, the next job does not get run even though the number of `crashers` is not zero!

```
jobs:
  fuzz-nightly-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      ...
      - name: Set crashers count
        working-directory: test/fuzz
        run: echo "::set-output name=crashers-count::$(find . -type d -name 'crashers' | xargs -I % sh -c 'ls % | wc -l' | awk '{total += $1} END {print total}')"
        id: set-crashers-count

   outputs:
     crashers-count: ${{ steps.set-crashers-count.outputs.crashers-count }}

  fuzz-nightly-fail:
    needs: fuzz-nightly-test
    if: ${{ needs.set-crashers-count.outputs.crashers-count != 0 }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      ...
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did a bunch of tests with a similar minimal example and I think I figured out the issue. Most immediately, in your `if` directive in your `fuzz-nightly-fail` job, you need to be accessing `needs.<job_id>.outputs.<job_output_id>` rather than `needs.<step_id>.outputs.<job_output_id>`. Therefore, the `if` directive would become `if: ${{ needs.fuzz-nightly-test.outputs.crashers-count != 0 }}`.

Additionally, you should probably make a step output ID that's distinct from the job output ID to save yourself from some confusion about what context object is being referenced where. So, the `run` statement in your first job could be something like `run: echo "::set-output name=count::$(find . -type d -name 'crashers' | xargs -I % sh -c 'ls % | wc -l' | awk '{total += $1} END {print total}')"` and the job output would also be changed to `crashers-count: ${{ steps.set-crashers-count.outputs.count }}`. Putting this all together, we get

```yaml
jobs:
  fuzz-nightly-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      ...
      - name: Set crashers count
        working-directory: test/fuzz
        run: echo "::set-output name=count::$(find . -type d -name 'crashers' | xargs -I % sh -c 'ls % | wc -l' | awk '{total += $1} END {print total}')"
        id: set-crashers-count

   outputs:
     crashers-count: ${{ steps.set-crashers-count.outputs.count }}

  fuzz-nightly-fail:
    needs: fuzz-nightly-test
    if: ${{ needs.fuzz-nightly-test.outputs.crashers-count != 0 }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      ...
```

The reason for this isn't immediately obvious from the documentation alone, but the example [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-defining-outputs-for-a-job) implies that `<step_id>.outputs.foo` is different from `<job_id>.outputs.foo` - `jobs.job1.outputs.output1` is defined as that job's `steps.step1.outputs.test`.

You can see a (very) minimal example of this [here](https://github.com/jidicula/test-actions/blob/9484a9239d9551dd105ef88a4dc0ee11f218fa79/.github/workflows/main.yml), with its corresponding workflow run [here](https://github.com/jidicula/test-actions/actions/runs/542214706).

Comment: wow, thanks for pointing my mistake! should've notice that too.